# Transferring Data from Processor to Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a composite item processor as mentioned below. I process items in all processors represented by input object which represents one line from my data file. However, in processor 4, i do some calculation on each item and store it in a map and aggregate it for the whole file. I want to presist this Map in my writer. How can i pass this big map to Writer?

```
<bean id="myProcessors"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor"
        scope="step">
        <property name="delegates">
            <util:list>
                <ref bean="processor1" />
                <ref bean="processor2" />
                <ref bean="processor3" />
                <ref bean="processor4" />
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the right way, but you could store it into the context (for example JobExecutionContext) and retrieve it later. Take a look at [Common Batch Patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html) to see an example (section 11.8).

It's not a good solution because, by the springbatch design, the ItemWriter should write data received as output of an ItemProcessor. So, do not bypass it...

My suggestion would be to create a POJO class, with fields for key and value and their getters / setters. This way, the processor 4, could convert your map to a list. Thus, the writer could receive `List<? extends Object>` and process it naturally.

**--EDIT: complemented as requested**

I'm writing withou test the code, so take care.

Create a pojo like the one bellow.

```
public class OutputObject {
    private Map myMap;

    public Object getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map myMap) {
        this.myMap= myMap;
    }
}
```

Then, modify your "processor4" bean. I'm not quite sure, but if your are using CompositeItemProcessor, your processor should have a class signature like `public class Processor4 implements ItemProcessor<InputObject, OutputObject>`.

The InputObject is the object that you received from processor3. The OutputObject is the pojo that you created above. The implementation of the process method of  should be something like:

```
public OutputObject process(InputObject item) throws Exception {

   ...
   Map myMap = ....
   OutputObject out = new OutputObject();
   out.setMyMap(myMap);
   return out;
}
```

Finally, your ItemWriter#writer should be something like:

```
public void write(List<? extends OutputObject> items) throws Exception {
   ...
   Map myMap = items.get(0);
   ...
}
```

And thats it. As I said, I didn't tested. So, validate everything before. Write a POC to validate the concept.

Comment: You mean create a POJO which holds my Map and inject it to Processor and Write so both can use it. Can you post a config so i can understand. Thanks.

Comment: @user3222372 Complemented the original answer.

Comment: Bob, i have one more question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005816/processing-two-files-in-a-spring-batch