# Processing two files in a spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Have a requirement to read files in spring batch, process it and persist it as one feed. One feed contains 50% of the information. When i have to persist the final result from the feeds, i need combine them using a common field and persist it as if like one item. Please see example below.

```
Feed1 fields: A|B|C|D|E
Feed2 fields: A|I|J|K|L
```

Final information that i need to persist is like:

```
A|B|C|D|E|I|J|K|L
```

Please suggest how i can achieve this in my spring batch job.

Thanks.

Comment: Are your input files sorted on the field 'A'?

Comment: Jimmy, files are not sorted by field A.

Answer (score 2):

If your input files would have been sorted you could have created a custom ItemReader implementation that performs a merge-sort on the files.

If sorting the input files is not an option, I think you'll need to store one of the input files temporarily into a data store. Then you can read from the second input file and enrich the records with the fields retrieved from the data store in your processor.

Comment: I could sort the input file. But i am going to do chunk processing where i would be processing a subset of data. I am not sure how sorting would help here. Can you throw some more light here?
Can i do anything on the Item Writer side?

Comment: Well they don't necessarily need to be sorted, maybe I should have said ordered. If both input files have their records in the same order of your join-key (field A), you can implement a custom ItemReader solution where you read from both input files simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

(Very) late answer, but you could use a plugin like this to handle the sorting and subsequent merging operations: https://github.com/upcrob/spring-batch-sort-merge